# How to convert a character variable to date/time variable

Tags: r, datetime, character

I have a variable named "date_time" in R in the format `2021/03/16 00:00:00`... that continues on in 15 minute intervals up until `2022/06/30 23:45:00`.
R is classing this variable as a character, but I need it to be classed as a date/time variable or some other classification that will allow me to run line graphs etc.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: See `as_datetime()` from the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of date and time variables in R. The POSIXct class stores a date and a time, together with the time zone.  You can convert your character vector to this using `as.POSIXct(date_time)`.  However, there are a couple of things to watch out for.  In this case, your strings match one of the tryFormats used by as.POSIXct, so there is no need to supply a format, though it is usually good practice to do so.  The other parameter that could cause you problems is the timezone.  This will default to the current system time zone.  If you are in a region with daylight saving time, there could be gaps and overlaps in the time/date data. You need to think about what those times actually represent. For instance, you could avoid daylight savings problems by using `as.POSIXct(date_time, tz = "UTC")`, but only if your times are UTC/GMT values.  Incidentally, packages such as lubridate are very useful for working with dates and times in R, but for something this simple there is really no need to install and load a contributed package.